# how to pass a param to tag file (advanced way needed) in play framework

Tags: playframework

We are testing out a port from seam to play.  I need to do something
like this in our template.html file which is passed a parameter and
needs to pass that parameter to a tag....(excuse me if my terminology
is not correct as this is my first day in play)....

## {common_nav page:#{get 'page'/} /}

or I tried this too....

## {common_nav page:${page} /}

basically I have a pricing.html file that inherits template.html which
reuses a common_nav.html file and need to pass param from pricing.html
to common_nav.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the 'page' named parameter is defined in renderArgs, then you could do

```
#{common_nava page: page/}
```

Comment: worked great...I guess it must be magically defined in renderArgs already.